# Simple but disturbing problem about function "tensor.backward()" in PyTorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm learning PyTorch these days and the `backward()` funciton really confused me.
Let's go directly to my problem:

I defined some tensors and ops:

```

```
import torch
x = torch.ones(2,5,requires_grad=True)
y = x + 2
z = x*x
Y = torch.mean(y)
Z = torch.mean(z)
```

```

If I run this:

```
y.backward(torch.ones(2,5))
z.backward(torch.ones(2,5))
```

no error occured.

**But, if I run this:**

```
Y.backward()
Z.backward()
```

I got:

```
    RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-732c4cd53ca7> in <module>()
      1 Y.backward()
----> 2 Z.backward()

E:\learningsoft\anadonda\lib\site-packages\torch\tensor.py in backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
     91                 products. Defaults to ``False``.
     92         """
---> 93         torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
     94 
     95     def register_hook(self, hook):

E:\learningsoft\anadonda\lib\site-packages\torch\autograd\__init__.py in backward(tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph, grad_variables)
     88     Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(
     89         tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph,
---> 90         allow_unreachable=True)  # allow_unreachable flag
     91 
     92 

RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time, but the buffers have already been freed. Specify retain_graph=True when calling backward the first time.
```

Could someone tell me **why they have different results?**

---

Let's me give more examples:
[example1(picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPs2s.png)

Comment: In fact, my main problem is, when will pytorch destory the graph? In my first situation, the graph still remained after the first backward. But in my second situation, the graph was freed after the first backward function.

Comment: The error in the second case is due to the buffers already been freed. In simple operations as in the first case (addition), there's no need of using buffers so PyTorch doesn't check if buffers were freed thus it doesn't raise the error. While in second case PyTorch needs buffers to store the result of x*x. Source: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/understanding-graphs-and-state/224/2?u=kharshit

Answer (score 0):

It's the order in which you are running the commands.

First you run backward on `y` and `z`. Then you run it on `Y` and `Z`, **but** `Y` and `Z` are based on `y` and `z` - which have already had backward run on them.

You need to run backward on `y` and `z` then reset the kernel, then redo the calculation and run backward on `Y` and `Z`.

```
x = torch.ones(2,5,requires_grad=True)
y = x + 2
z = x*x
Y = torch.mean(y)
Z = torch.mean(z)
```

```
y.backward(torch.ones(2,5))
z.backward(torch.ones(2,5))
```

Then reset.

```
x = torch.ones(2,5,requires_grad=True)
y = x + 2
z = x*x
Y = torch.mean(y)
Z = torch.mean(z)
```

```
Y.backward()
Z.backward()
```